# Construct Compound Protobuf Messages in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Given the following protobuf message types,

```
message Simple {
    optional double value = 1;
}

message Compound {
    optional Simple simple = 1;
}
```

the only way I could find to initialize a message of type `Compound` in C++ was to do the following rather laborious:

```
Compound compound;
Simple* simple_ptr = compound.mutable_simple();
simple_ptr->set_value(1.0);
```

While it may not seem terrible, suppose you made the example a little more realistic, making `Simple` contain 3 `double`s, and `Compound` contain 2 `Simple`s.  The code gets very repetitive very fast, in a seemingly (to me) quite unnecessary fashion.  If the classes were standard C++ classes, the instantiation would be very simple:

```
Compound compound(Simple(a, b, c), Simple(x, y, z));
```

I'm wondering if there's a more convenient way to construct protobuf messages.  I'm especially curious about using the `get_mutable` methods for this purpose, is there a more direct way?